# Allow sudo privileges without system shutdown and restart permissions

Tags: ubuntu

I have a bunch of users who are in the sudo group but I only want a couple of them to have the ability to shut down or restart the machine. I do not want to remove them from the supergroup as I still want them to be able to install system-wide software etc.

Is it possible to have this setup with ubuntu? Should I create a new group with some elevated permissions but without the system shutdown/restart bits? How can one do this?

Comment: What if they do `sudo /bin/sh` followed by `shutdown`?

Comment: Assuming they are not going out of their way to do this.

Comment: https://man.archlinux.org/man/sudoers.5.en https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/36650/exclude-commands-from-users-sudo-permissions